# Linked question score overflows box

Tags: bug, design

If a linked question has triple-digit votes, this overflows the box. One example: [Logging "password with counter" use](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57468/logging-password-with-counter-use) (links to a question with 111 votes).

[image: A linked question with 111 votes, displayed as 11 + 1]

Comment: Thanks Jan, somebody else actually mentioned this a few weeks ago... Hoping that SEI will fix it soon...

Comment: Also see the q on Meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229751/135923